# C# как создать файл для хранения данных

Tags: c#

Создаю приложение для подготовки к олимпиаде. И хочу чтобы после входа в систему сохранялись все данные из базы данных

```
user_info user = new user_info();
user.id = int.Parse(dt1.Rows[0][0].ToString());
user.email = dt1.Rows[0][2].ToString();
user.password = dt1.Rows[0][3].ToString();
user.name = dt1.Rows[0][4].ToString();
user.l_name = dt1.Rows[0][5].ToString();
user.office_id = dt1.Rows[0][6].ToString();
user.birth_date = dt1.Rows[0][7].ToString();
```

```
namespace AirPort
{
    internal class user_info
    {
        public int id;

        public string email { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string l_name { get; set; }
        public string office_id { get; set; }
        public string birth_date { get; set; }

        public user_info()
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Все данные сохраняются но когда пытаюсь взять их из другой формы они удаляются

Comment: По приведённому куску кода невозможно дать никакой диагноз. Тут важно как вы дальше эти данные записываете в файл и читаете.

Comment: База данных это разве не созранённые данные? Проблема не ясна. Если класс в файл записать - поизучайте это https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to